# Nearest set of coordinates but excluding current coordinates and blanks from dataset

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My question builds off of the one asked here and the accepted answer:

[Find the nearest set of coordinates in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28384055/find-the-nearest-set-of-coordinates-in-excel)

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28385295/3123109) there provides two solutions:

1. Non-circular distance:

   ```
   =LOOKUP(1,1/FREQUENCY(0,MMULT((B$1:C$10-E1:F1)^2,{1;1})),A$1:A$10)
   ```
2. Circular distance:

   ```
   =LOOKUP(1,1/FREQUENCY(0,SIN((RADIANS(B$1:B$10-E1))/2)^2+SIN((RADIANS(C$1:C$10-F1))/2)^2*COS(RADIANS(B$1:B$10))*COS(RADIANS(E1))),A$1:A$10)
   ```

However, that dataset looks like this:

[image]

I'm trying to work with a dataset that looks like the following:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is:

- Fill in `G` and `H` where they are empty.
- If `G` and `H` is empty, look at `E` and `F` (e.g. `G2` and `H2` are empty, so get the coordinates from `E2` and `F2`).
- Search all `E` and `F` for the next closest coordinates ***where `G` and `H` are not blank***.
- Return the value of `G` and `H`.

All I have so far is modifying the Non-circular solution:

```
=LOOKUP(1,1/FREQUENCY(0,MMULT(($E$2:$F$69778-E2:F2)^2,{1;1})),$H$2:$H$69778)
```

Of course with this, it just matches to itself and `G` and `H` are blank so it returns nothing.

**Any suggestions for how to implement this?**

As a last resort I can always just copy to a separate tab all of the rows with values in `G` and `H` and do the lookup against that. Trying to implement it without doing that first however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original formula is a bit hard to understand but uses the behaviour of Frequency and Lookup in a very efficient way. It avoids the need to re-calculate the differences and their squares which would be needed if you used the more obvious method of finding the minimum squared difference and looking it up in a list of the squared differences.

Short answer - you could easily tweak the non-circular formula by adding a large number to the non-blank rows:

```
=LOOKUP(1,1/FREQUENCY(0,MMULT((B$1:C$10-E1:F1+999*(D$1:D$10<>""))^2,{1;1})),A$1:A$10)
```

[image]

This gives E where the original formula would have given D.

The same with the circular formula, I think I'm right in saying that the value of this version of the haversine formula can never exceed 1, so try:

```
=LOOKUP(1,1/FREQUENCY(0,SIN((RADIANS(B$1:B$10-E1))/2)^2+SIN((RADIANS(C$1:C$10-F1))/2)^2*COS(RADIANS(B$1:B$10))*COS(RADIANS(E1))+10*(D1:D10<>"")),A$1:A$10)
```

*Notes*

If I were doing this now and starting from scratch, I would probably use Let and Xlookup in Excel 365 to make it easier to read.

As has been mentioned in a comment, there should be a latitude correction to the first formula to make it [approximately correct over short distances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664799/calculating-distance-between-two-points-using-pythagorean-theorem).