# Calculating the distance of geo locations

Tags: javascript, math, geolocation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Distance Between Two GEO Locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838493/distance-between-two-geo-locations)

How can I calculate the distance between two geo locations. (Latitude and Longitude)

Answer (score 4):

This site might help you

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html