# Geolocation: filter by proximity

Tags: javascript, json, geolocation, geocoding

I have a list of users from across the world in JSON format. Each item in the list has a location information.

1. How do I convert these locations to proper longitude and latitude?
2. How do I filter these locations to get only locations within 50 miles of my current location (assuming I know how to get current longitude and latitude).

Is there a Service that I can use?

Do I really need to convert these locations to longitude and latitudes? Essentially all I want to do is find locations withing 50 miles of current location and ignore others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the free [geonames.org webservice](http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html) for that. There is a [search method](http://www.geonames.org/export/geonames-search.html) available where you can give a location name and get latitude and longitude for any location. Be aware that there may be multiple locations with the same name available. See the example here: http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?q=london&maxRows=10&username=demo

For your second question, there are multiple approaches. The basic algorithms are outlined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420045/how-to-find-distance-from-the-latitude-and-longitude-of-two-locations), but probably the easiest way is to use the Google Maps API (see second answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838493/distance-between-two-geo-locations)).

Answer (score 1):

I’ve done this in the past, at it’s not something one can do simply with just JavaScript & JSON. The best way is to create a MySQL database that uses spatial `Point` commands. If you want JavaScript & JSON, then you would have to create a webservice—using PHP for example—to manage the queries between the JavaScript & MySQL database. It seems daunting at first, but once you get the hang of it, it’s quite cool.  I recommend [reading this site](http://www.xarg.org/2009/12/people-near-you-with-mysql/) to understand the basics.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was hoping there would be some nosql solution with node.js? Anyway to utilize this http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/geospatial-indexes/