# Distance measurment by the GPS coordinates

Tags: c, math, gps

How to calculate the distance between 2 places by using the GPS coordinates?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420045/how-to-find-distance-from-the-latitude-and-longitude-of-two-locations

Comment: You may be using this algorithm in an embedded environment but there is nothing in the question to link it to embedded computing.  Question re-tagged.

Answer (score 3):

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/**Great-circle_distance**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance)

(Pythagorean theorem won't be enough because of earth's sphericity)